# ¿Como se puede obtener el valor máximo de la id en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp

Quiero obtener la id con el valor máximo para que se muestre en la vista solo el que tenga el valor más alto. Ahora muestra todos los registros de la tabla, pero busco que solo muestre el que tenga el tenga el id con mayor valor.

*AdminController.cs*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Confirm()
{
    var oTBCContext = _context.OrdenTrabajo.Include(o => o.FkCategoriaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkComunaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkEmpresaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkUsuarioNavigation).Include(o => o.FkComunaNavigation.FkRegionNavigation);

    return View(await oTBCContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si tu id es auto incrementable, entonces tu valor mas alto seria el ultimo registro que se inserto, esto lo puedes solucionar fácilmente con un OrderByDescending al id, haciéndolo de esta manera.

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.tuId)
```

observando tu codigo, quedaria mas o menos asi

```
var oTBCContext = _context.OrdenTrabajo.Include(o => o.FkCategoriaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkComunaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkEmpresaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkUsuarioNavigation).Include(o => o.FkComunaNavigation.FkRegionNavigation).OrderByDescending(x => x.tuId);
```

en caso de que no se autoincrementable, puedes usar `Max`,
que lo usarias de esta manera

```
..Max(x => x.tuId)
```

basandome en tu codigo, porque no especificas a que tabla se debe saber el id mas alto, entonces se buscaria en `OrdenTrabajo`

```
  var oTBCContext = _context.OrdenTrabajo.Max(x=>x.id).Include(o => o.FkCategoriaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkComunaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkEmpresaNavigation).Include(o => o.FkUsuarioNavigation).Include(o => o.FkComunaNavigation.FkRegionNavigation);
```

otra cosa, estas devolviendo una lista, entonces te devolvera desde el valor mas alto al mas bajo,en caso de que solo buscas obtener el ultimo valor, sin contar el resto, entonces cambia **ToListAsync** por **FirstOrDefaultAsync**, esto te devuelve el ultimo valor con el id mas alto

Comment: Muchas gracias, logré implementarlo diciendo como lo indicas.